# Show more with php loop and jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, loops, show-hide

I am looping a about forty strings using php.  I am currently using `substr()` to only display the first 170 characters.  I am using jQuery to hide the rest of the string and to create a link to show the rest.  This is the code I am looping:

```
echo "<span>" . $substring_1 . "</span><span class='dotdot'>...</span><span class='readmore'>" . $substring_2 . "</span><a href='#' class='clickmore'>Show more</a>";
```

Here is the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".readmore").hide();
    $(".clickmore").click(function() {
        $(".dotdot").hide();
        $(".readmore").show();
    });
});
```

This code works, however, I would like this to only "show more" for the individual string.  Right now, because I am using the class selector, when I click "show more", it "shows more" for every instance in the loop.

Is there a way to only "show more" for the instance of the loop I am clicking on?

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `$(this)` and  `prev()`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".readmore").hide();
    $(".clickmore").click(function() {
        $(this).prev().prev(".dotdot").hide();      //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        $(this).prev(".readmore").show();    //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".readmore").hide();
    $(".clickmore").click(function() {
        $(this).prev().prev(".dotdot").hide();      //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        $(this).prev(".readmore").show();    //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>This is</span><span class='dotdot'>...</span><span class='readmore'> Complete string</span><a href='#' class='clickmore'>Show more</a>

<hr />
<span>This is</span><span class='dotdot'>...</span><span class='readmore'> Complete string</span><a href='#' class='clickmore'>Show more</a>

<hr />
<span>This is</span><span class='dotdot'>...</span><span class='readmore'> Complete string</span><a href='#' class='clickmore'>Show more</a>
```

Comment: For some reason, this does not work. Do I need to change some html code?